# Show that X and -X are identically distributed and their moment, $M_{x}(t)$ is even

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let's assume X is a random variable with an even pdf.

To show that X and -X are identically distributed, we need to prove that $F_X(x)=F_-X(x)$.  We also know that X having an even pdf means $f_X(x)=-f_X(x)$.  What I did here is that I took the integral of $f_X(x)$ and $-f_X(x)$ both from negative infinity to x and set them equal to each other.  When we integrate this we should get $F_X(x)=F_-X(x)$, right?

I'm not so sure how to show that $M_x(t)$, or the moment is even.  Do we just do $M_x(t)=-M_x(-t)$ and infer our results from there?

Comment: you mean $f_X(x) = f_X(-x)$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the first part OK. For the second part you need to show that $M_X(-t)=M_X(t)$, which you can do by making use of the first part:

\begin{eqnarray*}
M_X(-t) &=& \; E(e^{-tx}) \\
&=& \; E(e^{t(-x)}) \\
&=& \; M_{-X}(t) \\
&=& \; M_X(t)\qquad\qquad\text{since $X$ and $-X$ are identically distributed.}
\end{eqnarray*}